# Proving fixed points of a continuous function

Tags: functions

**Prove that every continuous function $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ has a fixed point.**

What does the statement $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,1]$ mean? I have never studied function rigorously so I am not well-versed with the notation.

Can somebody help me out or provide some resources that may prove beneficial?

Comment: It means the fuction is defined on the interval $[0,1]$, and the image of a number in this interval belongs to $[0,1]$.

Comment: I am not sure I understood that. Can you elaborate it a little more?

Comment: $f(x)$ exists for all $x\in[0,1]$ and $0\le f(x)\le 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the **domain** of the function is $[0,1]$ and that the **codomain** of the function is $[0,1]$. An example of such a function would be $x^2$, for example, or maybe $\sin(x)$ or an infinitely many other functions.

To solve your problem, here's a couple guidelines:

Take a look at the function $g(x)=f(x)-x$.

1. What is the sign of $g(0)$?
2. What is the sign of $g(1)$?
3. What does the intermediate value theorem tell you?

Comment: So is this correct? If in a function $f$, we input any number from the interval [0,1], it will output a unique number from the interval [0,1] each time. (The output is always the same for an input but is unique)

Comment: @FaiqRaees No, the output may not be unique. The function $f$ defined as $f(x)=x(1-x)$, for example, outputs $0$ for the input $0$ and the input $1$.

Comment: Oh yes, I confused the vertical line test. What I meant was for every input there can't be two different outputs. Btw why is the codomain [0,1]? I guess it could be anything. No?

Comment: @FaiqRaees It simply means that in the function $f$, you input a number from $[0,1]$, and for each number, it will output *exactly one* number from $[0,1]$.

Comment: @FaiqRaees No, the codomain must be $[0,1]$ for the statement to work. If  the codomain was anything, then the function may not have a fixed point. For example, $f:[0,1]\to[0,2]$ defined as $f(x)=x+1$ **does not have a fixed point**.

Comment: I am aware of that but I am inquiring is there any significance for the use of exactly same codomain?

Comment: @FaiqRaees I just answered that.

Comment: Just one last question. $f(x) = x$ is defined over $[0,1]$ will always have a codomain of $[0,1]$, and it is continuous yet it doesn't have a fixed point. Isn't this a counter example to the statement asked to prove?

Comment: @FaiqRaees $0$ is a fixed point for $f(x)=x$. and $0.5$ is also a fixed point for $f(x)=x$. In fact, **every point in $[0,1]$** is a fixed point for $f(x)=x$.

Comment: @FaiqRaees Remember, a fixed point of a function is such a point $x_0$ that $f(x_0)=x_0$. If $f(x)=x$, then $f(x_0)=x_0$ for every point!

Comment: Oh Okay got it. Thank you very very much

Comment: So is this answer correct? Assuming $f(0), f(1)$ aren't fixed points then $g(0)>0$ and $g(1)<0$ and by IMT there exist a x such that $0<x<1$ for which $g(x) = 0$ and hence its a fixed point. If our assumption is incorrect, then it automatically answers the question.

Comment: @FaiqRaees Sounds about right. Maybe just add a short sentence why $g(x)=0$ means that $x$ is a fixed point. It's more or less obvious, but it can't hurt :)

Comment: It would be this? right? If $g(x)=0$ then $f(x)=x$ which is the definition for a fixed point.

Comment: @FaiqRaees Exactly. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

The notation $f:X\to Y$, where $X$ and $Y$ are sets means that $f$ is a function that to each element in $X$ assigns a unique element in $Y$. $X$ and $Y$ could be intervals, like $[0,1]$, they could be thw whole number line $\Bbb R$, or any other set, like $\Bbb N$ or $\{a, b, c, d\}$.

$X$ and $Y$ may be the same set, or they may not. However, in the specific context of analysing fixed-points, it doesn't make sense unless they are the same, or at least very close to it.

Comment: In this case what is the difference between X and Y? They seem same to me.

Comment: @FaiqRaees As I said, they may be the same, they may not be the same. There is nothing really special about either case. In this specific problem they _are_ the same. It just means that $f$ assigns, to any point $x$ in $[0,1]$, a unique point in $[0,1]$ called $f(x)$. A fixed point in this case is a point which $f$ assigns to itself.

Comment: So is this correct? If in a function $f$, we input any number from the interval [0,1], it will output a unique number from the interval [0,1] each time. (The output is always the same for an input but is unique). So for example f(0.5) = 0.97 and f(0)= 0.23.

Comment: @FaiqRaees Essentially, yes. But I caution that it depends on what you mean by "unique". It does _not_ mean that different inputs necessarily give different outputs (that's a property called "injectivity", and not a necessity for a function, but some functions do have that property). For instance, a function that always returns $0.5$ no matter what the input is is allowed. However, any given input yields one and _only one_ output, and in that sense it is unique. A function is not allowed to return both $0.3$ and $0.7$ simultaneously for a single input.

Answer (score -1):

Topology does assume that you know some basic set theory, among which the definition of functions.

If $X,Y$ are sets a function $f:X \to Y$ is just a set of pairs $f = \{x,y): x \in X. y \in Y\}$, such that whenever $(x,y) \in f$ and $(x,y') \in f$ we have $y=y'$ and for all $x \in x, \exists y \in Y: (x,y) \in f$ (every $x \in X$ has a unique image in $Y$, the unique $y$ for $x$ such that $(x,y) \in f$ is usually written $f(x) \in Y$.

Here we are in the situation that $X=Y=[0,1]$ and a fixed point, is an $x \in [0,1]$ such that $f(x) = x$.

Comment: If the OP doesn't even know the definition of a function, there is no point bombarding him with topology.

Comment: @YvesDaoust all I did was give him the definition of function , no topology at all

Comment: I said topology for short. You are using  a lot of other concepts thta the OP probably knows even less. And if you use nothing from topology, why do you mention it ?